Longitude and Latitude in RHO points to natural coordinate in ncdf4 file in R
I have a URL on the pH of the gulf of Alaska. I cannot open the variable normally (
dput(`pH <- ncvar_get(nc, "pH")`)

) because the dataset is too big, so I should choose some subsets. This variable has 4 dimensions: time, depth, latitude and longitude in rho points. I need to extrapolate the dataset from specific locations (that I know in natural coordinates) in the gulf of Alaska. My question is how do I get this data? What are the commands on R to get this data? Do I need to look for something in specific?
I tried to use other packages (raster or oce) but it did not really work. I have the the maximum and minimum latitude and longitude in both rho-points and natural coordinates. I tried to ask to Chat GPT for some commands (like the "neighbor approach") that could help me pinpoint the areas that I need, but it did not work as well.
This is my code so far:
library (ncdf4)
#Getting the file 
url <- "https://thredds.aoos.org/thredds/dodsC/AOOS_GAK_ROMS_BGC_V2_MONTHLY_DIAG.nc"
nc <- nc_open(url)

# getting to know the variables
names(nc$var)


# getting variable pH characteristics since is to be to open like any other variable 
pH_var <- nc$var$"pH"
pH_dim_names <- pH_var$dim
print(pH_dim_names)
print(pH)
## these are all the four dimensions of the variable: eta_rho, xi_rho, depth and ocean_time 

# time 
ocean_time_dim <- nc$dim$"ocean_time"
print(ocean_time_dim)

## We know that the length is 348 units 
## we know that the units is "seconds since 1900-01-01 00:00:00", which means that for example the first variable 2936131200 represents the number of seconds since 1900-01-01
## we also know that the dataset range is from 1993-01-01T00:00:00Z to 2021-12-31T00:00:00Z


# the goal is to turn the units in seconds to monthly average where YY-MM-DD
start_timestamp <- as.numeric(ocean_time_dim$start)
time_values_seconds <- ocean_time_dim$vals
time_values <- as.POSIXct(time_values_seconds, origin = "1900-01-01", tz = "UTC")
### To check the numbers: 
print(head(time_values))
print(tail(time_values))
print(tail(time_values, 10))



# depth 
depth <- ncvar_get(nc, "depth")
print(depth)
dim(depth)
class(depth)
summary (depth)

## so we know that there are 33 values.
## the range goes from 0 (max measure) to -5500 (min measure)

## latitude and longitude

lon <- ncvar_get (nc, "lon")
lat <- ncvar_get(nc, "lat")

attributes(lon)
attributes (lat)
class(lon)
class (lat)

longitude_range <- range(lon)
print(longitude_range)
latitude_range <-range(lat)
print (latitude_range)

lon_attrs <- ncatt_get(nc, "lon")
lat_attrs <- ncatt_get(nc, "lat")
print(lon_attrs)
print(lat_attrs)

### the dimensions are 326 and 282 (?)
### it's a matrix and array 
### the range for the latitude is  47.99876 <->65.25184
### the range for the longitude is 197.9042<-> 228.9531

## we know that this is the latitude and longitude are in RHO-points, so they are not natural coordinates 
## the question is that how do i turn them into natural coordinates 

## I know from the metadata: 
#### the geographical North= 62 and South= 48
### the geographical bound coort East = -133 and West = -163

